# Date and DateTime in Instant and multiple timezones

Tags: java, hibernate, java-time

regarding by [image]

I trying to change all java.util.Date to java.time.Instant in all my hibernate entities.
saving Instant as timestamp with time zone.

How to mark somehow Instant as Date or DateWithTime, to keep type (Date or DateWithTime) clear?

It can be saved as ZonedDateTime/ZonedDate but in single server i have multiple timezones per tenant and want to work transparently with Instant.

Comment: For a date without time of day why not use `LocalDate` in Java and `date` in SQL as the table says?

Comment: yes @OleV.V. i choice that option.
I create ZonedDateTime.now()withZoneSameInstant(UTC).toLocalDate(); and work with LocalDate only in UTC